# Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources

Tags: gradle, plugins, version, jetbrains-ide

```
Build file '---------\build.gradle' line: 5

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.0.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Build file '---------\build.gradle' line: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem mainly because of kotlin plugin version incorrect. There is not such version of org.jetbrains.kotlin.android as 1.0.0, The next version of kotlin plugin after 0.1.1.2-5-test-5 was 1.1.1 and Current stable release is 1.8.22.
Here is the [documentation of kotlin plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.kotlin.android) in Gradle website and here is the [documentation of kotlin release notes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html) in it's official website.